# How i can send file in body of the post request? groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a file as a byte array. I want to send it in the body of a post request.

I have an example in JavaScript that works great. Can't repeat the same code in groovy. The server returns "Initial Server Error". I'm sure the problem is in the type of data being passed.

Groovy code:

```
def reqParams = [:];
reqParams.filename = 'test.pdf'
reqParams.filedata = utils.readFileContent(obj.clientFile) // array of byte
reqParams.destination = 'test'

def jsonBody = new JsonBuilder(reqParams).toString()

// build HTTP POST

def client = new RESTClient(baseUrl)
client.auth.basic 'user1', 'user1'
def resp = client.post(body : jsonBody, contentType: JSON)
```

Example body of request generating with help JS:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------295349461296500421390407
Content-Length: 659
----------------------------295349461296500421390407
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="query.txt"

<query.txt>
----------------------------295349461296500421390407
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="destination"

workspace://SpacesStore/716afb88-715a-4413-85bc-f71630abfd51
----------------------------295349461296500421390407
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

jasperTextToNextStrin.txt

----------------------------295349461296500421390407--
```

How I can send POST request with Groovy?

Comment: For multipart form data similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870172/encoder-function-for-multipart-form-data-in-groovy

Answer (score 0):

The JSON format doesn't natively support binary data. To send binary data in a JSON payload you would need to encode it as text somehow.

What encoding you should use depends on what the server expects.

A common encoding would be [base 64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

```
reqParams.filedata = myFile.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
```

or

```
reqParams.filedata = utils.readFileContent(obj.clientFile).encodeBase64().toString()
```

if `readFileContent` indeed returns a `byte[]`.